# How to load scss style in ssr intial render for nextjs with react js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've a next js project in typescript with inbuilt scss. The style loading approach is as per official documentation provided by next js and it's loading fine in browser. But, the issue I'm having is on inital load or when I refresh, the style is loaded only after page loads. So, there is some millisecond of page render without any style. How can I resolve this issue? I've digged around and found solution with jsx styled component. But, since my whole style is in separate scss and the project already in ready state, I can't choose to go that way. Is there any way where I can load scss style even on inital render without any delay of style loading on ssr.